# Git cherry-pick fail

Tags: git, version-control, cherry-pick

I have a local brand new branch and I want to cherry pick some commits. A few picks ran OK but the next one produced a conflict:

```
>git cherry-pick 676b371
error: could not apply 676b371... fixed connection resolution.
hint: after resolving the conflicts, mark the corrected paths
hint: with 'git add <paths>' or 'git rm <paths>'
hint: and commit the result with 'git commit'
```

So I tried to look what's wrong and got this:

```
>git status
On branch MyBranch
fatal: Could not open file .git/rebase-merge/done for reading: No such file or directory
```

What does it mean? My repo is broken? How do I fix that?

**Update:**
ran as suggested:

```
>git cherry-pick --abort

>git status
On branch MyBranch
fatal: Could not open file .git/rebase-merge/done for reading: No such file or directory
```

**Update2:**
this is a content of .git/rebase-merge folder:

```
git-rebase-todo
git-rebase-todo.backup
head-name
interactive
onto
orig-head
quiet
```

p.s.

git version 2.10.1.windows.1

Comment: What if you use `git cherry-pick --abort` to stop pick the commit `676b371`, and then use `git status` to check what's your git repo's state? If your working directory is clean, then cherry-pick the commit by `git cherry-pick 676b371`.

Comment: @Marina-MSFT, thanks, updated my question.

Comment: Please check in your `.git` folder and find if you have the file `.git/rebase-merge/done`. If has, please remove the `rebase-merge/done`  file and subfolder, then try `git status`.

Comment: Updated the question. Even if I switch to another branch I still get the error. I do need to recover from the situation somehow as some of my branches aren't pushed to a remote :(

Comment: Didn't you delete the `rebase-merge` folder and file in it? It is generated when you cherry-pick a commit while some error occur. So it's useless.

Comment: I never touch `.git` folder.

Comment: `.git` folder was auto generated when you initial a git repo, it's the place where commit history, log, hooks etc stored in. I mean the `rebase-merge` folder is useless. And when your git repo works fine again, you will find the `rebase-merge` folder is gone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38793538/fatal-could-not-open-file-git-rebase-merge-done-for-reading-no-such-file-or-d):

```
git rebase --abort
```

That did the trick.